# Excel 2010 offset function returns #VALUE! error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use the offset function in excel 2010, but it gives me a `#VALUE!` error.
The function works perfectly, if it's like this:

`=OFFSET(GASUK!$AB$2,0,0,((COUNTA(GASUK!$AB$2:$AB$1000)-(COUNTIF(GASUK!$AB$2:$AB$1000,"")))))`

but in my case I need it to be locked a little further, I have to change `AB2` to `AB193`.

So when I rewrite the reference everywhere to `$AB$193` it gives a `#VALUE!` error, why?
So for some reason this does not work:

`=OFFSET(GASUK!$AB$193,0,0,((COUNTA(GASUK!$AB$193:$AB$1000)-(COUNTIF(GASUK!$AB$193:$AB$1000,"")))))`

I don't understand why. I doesn't go off the spreadsheet or something like that.

Comment: What are you expecting your `OFFSET` function to do? It may be your first formula is working but not for the reasons you think it is.

Comment: I'm expecting it to return a range of values. I'm using charts, to represent some financial data, and the data tables in excel are updated manually, so the chart needs to be dynamic. This means that the Axis of the chart needs to have the function, which delivers the range of available dates. This is why I use offset. I expect it to return a range of values for the chart.

Comment: And are you copying this formula down for every row in your table? It might help to post a screenshot of your spreadsheet (feel free to anonymise the data) - you can upload it to imgur.com and edit your post to include the link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

So is the idea to return all the values from AB193 until the last non-blank value? If so try using `INDEX` like this

`=GASUK!$AB$193:INDEX(GASUK!$AB$193:$AB$1000,MATCH(2,1/(GASUK!$AB$193:$AB$1000<>"")))`

Comment: Thanks the formula works like a charm! On a side note, I've figured out, that even the original formula gave a #VALUE! error, it still works in a chart, no problem.